# find the longest path in a maze

Tags: python, python-3.x, maze

I want to find the longest path that starts at a certain point.The route crosses only points 1.
How can I save all the routes and find the longest ones,

```
    def ff(m,position,n): 
        if position==(n-1,n-1):
            return [(n-1,n-1)]

        (x,y)=position

        if x+1<n and m[x+1][y]==1:
            path=ff(m,(x+1,y),n)
            if path != None:
                return [(x,y)]+path

        if y+1<n and m[x][y+1]==1:
            path =ff (m,(x,y+1),n)
            if path != None:
                return [(x,y)]+path
```

Comment: for example
m=[  [1,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,1]  ]


print(ff(m,(0,0),4))